Как сделать тип stage необязательным?
как мне сделать тип stage необязательным пропсом в ReturnType<typeof useView>?
const MainView = ({ form, functions }: ReturnType<typeof useView> )  => {}

export const useView = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [stage, setStage] = useState<'email' | 'password' | 'about'>('email')
    const signUpForm = useForm<EmailFormScheme | PasswordFormScheme>({
        mode: 'onChange',
        defaultValues: {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        },
        resolver: zodResolver(stage === 'email' ? emailFormScheme : stage === 'password' ? passwordFormScheme : emailFormScheme)
    })

    const onSubmit = signUpForm.handleSubmit(value => {
        if(stage === 'email' && 'email' in value) {
            navigate('stage=1')
            setStage('password')
        }
    })

    return {
        form: signUpForm,
        stage,
        functions: { onSubmit }
    }
}


Где сам тип? Ну а если пальцем в небо, то для необязательного поставить знак вопроса

тип useView автоматом определяется на основе возвращаемых свойств , просто я решил что писать вручную тип для useView такое себе и через returnType вернуть напрямую тип из функции будет лучше, но как его диструктуризировать и сделать stage необязательным не знаю( Может всё таки написать тип для useView будет лучше и там уже сделать stage необязательным .

Omit<ReturnType<typeof useView>, 'stage'> & Partial<Pick<ReturnType<typeof useView>, 'stage'>>

или можно использовать вот этот хелпер https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/simplify.d.ts

спасибо большое!
